# Move and Remove

Tags: optimization, chess

[image]

From the initial position Black makes a regular move to an unoccupied square, and removes any piece from the board. Then repeats, alternately making a move and a removal. The objective is for Black to find a position where all the unoccupied squares are under attack.

a) How can Black make it with ten moves?

b) With only eight removed pieces?

Comment: Are the "ten moves" and "eight removed pieces" separate sub-questions? I don't see how they're compatible - if you've made ten moves, you've removed more than eight pieces.

Comment: Is castling and/or pawn promotion valid moves?

Comment: @bobble -yes separate , for these are the max & min

Comment: @risky mysteries-yes valid moves as regular moves

Comment: So when you say *"How can black make it with ten moves?"* you mean 10 moves + 9 removes? Or 10 moves + 10 remove? Or either? Or 5 moves + 5 removes? Thanks!

Comment: @risky mysteries-The two questions are with different solutions . In question (a) as long as in 10th move  all free squares are attacked, that is it.  The 10th removal is needed only if a piece is blocking the attack.  Also  in sub-question (b) the 9th move is needed if all the free squares are not yet attacked. It seems  both questions are equally optimal but not necessary to be posted in two separate questions.

Comment: * All unmoved pawns are in rank 7

Comment: "Attack all the unoccupied squares". Unoccupied when? Those that are unoccupied as they are now, as they will be after any given *n* moves, or does every square have to be attacked, as and when there is an opportunity? The problem isn't very clear, when a solution offers only 5 moves and the asker thinks it needs 10.

Comment: ... attacked at some time during the play, or is the task to find a position where every unoccupied square is "covered" on the board, at the same time?

Comment: After the required 10 moves (removal not considered a move) any unoccupied or vacated squares must be attacked by one or more pieces.

Comment: .. the most number of attacked free squares is 57

Comment: Thank you, I've been trying to solve a different problem.

Comment: Can you post your solution without pawn-promotion? I am at a loss!

Comment: Or if it's too mush trouble, just the ending position.

Comment: @riskymysteries I've taken the liberty. See updated answer if you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part 1: 10-mover

> 1.e7-e5 xa7 2.e5-e4 xb7 3.e4-e3 xc7 4.e3-e2 xd7 5. e2-e1Q xf7 6.Qd8-d5 xg7 7.Bf8-d6 xh7 8.Bd6-c7 xb8 9.Ra8-a2 xg8 10.Ke8-f7

Final position:

> [image]

Alternative with no promotion (final position only; reachable in 10 moves / 9 removals):

> [image]

Part 2: 8-remover

> 1.g7-g5 xa7 2.g5-g4 xb7 3.g4-g3 xc7 4.g3-g2 xd7 5.g2-g1Q xe7 6.Qd8-d3 xf7 7.Bf8-g7 xh7 8.Bg7-e5 xg8 9.Nb8-c6

Final position:

> [image]

Alternative without promotion (8m/8r):

> [image]

Aside: if we aim for a fast solution it can be done in

> 5 moves and 4 removals (3 if strict alternating is not required.

Proof game:

> 1.e7-e5 xh7 2.Rh8-h2 xd7 3.Qd8-d6 xa7 4.Ra8-a1 (xb7) 5.Bf8-e7

Final position:

> [image]

Comment: Good one! This is an early  solution for all free squares attacked in just  9 ply or 5 moves. But onward to next removal..xf7 ,and move 6.Ke8-f7 makes it further. The problem is how to reach 10th move while losing more pieces.

Comment: Right.10 moves is the upper limit and the 9 mover hints for solving the least moves. I didnt find a promotion solution so allowed it. I guess the solution for no promotion is unique.

Comment: @TSLF Wait, so there is also a no-promotion solution? If so, I'll look for it :)

Comment: @risky mysteries-Actually, you can..

Comment: Thank! I can't believe I have been fiddling around with 2 bishops for so long when I should've removed one of those!

Comment: Note: I based these 7 piece board attack from Jean Rondeau's post in  Fewest Chess Pieces question